# custom button for log a call with record type preselection

Tags: custom-button

is it possible to have a custom button for "log a call" with preselection of the record type instead of having the user to select a record type?

the url for the standard button looks like this

https://eu4.salesforce.com/setup/ui/recordtypeselect.jsp?ent=Task&retURL=%2F00157000020NCcs&save_new_url=%2F00T%2Fe%3Ftitle%3DAnruf%26who_id%3D00157000020NCcs%26what_id%3D00157000020NCcs%26followup%3D1%26tsk5%3DAnruf%26retURL%3D%252F00157000020NCcs

Thanks a lot in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using Salesforce Ajax Toolkit with a custom button. You have to fetch the required RecordType and associate it with the new Record. The JavaScript code will somehow look like this. (*Please note this code is for example only and is not a compiled one*)

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js")}

var custObj = new sforce.SObject("MyObject__c");
custObj.id = "{!MyObject__c.Id}";
var qr = sforce.connection.query("SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE SobjectType ='" + "MyObject__c" + "'" + " AND DeveloperName = '" + "RecordType_Name" + "'"); //Change the RecordType Name 
custObj.RecordTypeId = qr.records.Id;
window.location.href = URL; //Create your own URL here
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/00T/e?title=Call&who_id={!Lead.Id}&tsk5=Call&tsk4={!TODAY()}&RecordType=0123C000000a3kU&retURL=%2F{!Lead.Id}
```